# How to update a last viewed products array correctly

Tags: php, arrays, session

I got a list of last viewed products by a customer. This is done by adding product ids to a session and adding those ids to a query that shows the products. The session array must be only 3 ids long.

Ofcourse no duplicates can be added (if a person watches 3 products and after that 1 product three times, there will be only 1 last viewed product because it is the same id three times).

So I used `array_unique` for that like in the following code:

On a productpage:-

```
$_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = $productcr[0]['id'];
```

On the catalog page:-

```
if($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'] != ''){
    $result = array_unique($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']);
    $sessionlimit = array_slice($result, -3);
    $prods  = implode(",", $sessionlimit);

    $laatst = "SELECT * FROM `snm_content` WHERE id IN ($prods) and state = 1 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3";
```

My issue is this:-

When I watch for example product number 1 and after that watch products 2 3 4, the ids contain 2,3,4 like it should, but when I watch 1 again it isn't added. The array will still contain 2,3,4 because it checks for uniques.

If I print `$result` this is what is shown:-

```
Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 8 [2] => 5 [4] => 6 )
```

and if I print `$sessionlimit` this is the result:-

```
Array ( [0] => 8 [1] => 5 [2] => 6 )
```

Even when I open the product with id 7 again, it is not added to the array `($sessionlimit)`.

How can I get that to work like I want?

Comment: Instead of $_SESSION['laatstbekeken'][] = $productcr[0]['id']; try to use array_unshift($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'], $productcr[0]['id']); The latest watch product will be first on list.

Answer (score 0):

You can get your desired output by using array_reverse function try below codes

```
   if($_SESSION['laatstbekeken'] != ''){
    $result = array_unique(array_reverse($_SESSION['laatstbekeken']));
    $prods  = implode(",", array_slice($result,0,3));
}
```

Comment: did you try this?